# The mean of $f$ minimizes $||f-\xi||_p$ over all $\xi\in\Bbb R$. [Reference request]

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, reference-request

I would like to know where I can find a reference for the following fact:

> Let $\Omega$ be a set of finite measure, $1<p<\infty$ and $f\in L^p(\Omega,\mu)$. Denote $\bar f:=\frac 1{|\Omega|} \int_\Omega f d\mu$. Then
>   $$
> \bar f = \arg\min \{ ||f-\xi||_p :  \xi\in\Bbb R \}.
> $$

For $p=2$ the result is extremely well-known whereas for $p=1$ the above doesn't hold.

I am surprise that I couldn't find a reference for the above result for a general $p>1$ since I assumed it to be somewhat well-known as well. Does anyone know a book where this theorem is stated?

Answer (score 3):

There is no such reference, because the result is not true for $p\ne 2$.

Let $\Omega=(0,3)$, $f = \chi_{(0,1)}$. Then for $s\in \mathbb R$,
$$
g(s):=\int_\Omega |f-s|^p = |s-1|^p + 2|s|^p.
$$
Now clearly $s<0$ is not a minimum, as well as $s>1$. For $s\in (0,1)$, the derivative of $g$ is given by
$$
g'(s) = p( 2s^{p-1} - (1-s)^{p-1} ).
$$
The integral mean of $f$ is $1/3$, so 
$$
g'(1/3)= p\ 3^{1-p}\ (2 - \cdot 2^{p-1}) = p\ 3^{1-p}\ 2(1-2^{p-2}),
$$
which is zero if and only if $p=2$.

For $p=1$ the minimum is at $s=0$. Does this qualify as median?

Comment: Thank you for the general $p>1$ case, I should have checked first whether the statement is true or not. By the way, for $p=1$ I confused what I wanted to say with another statement, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

This result only holds for $p = 2$. Indeed, if we denote
$$J(\xi) = \int_\Omega |f - \xi|^p \, \mathrm d\mu,$$
we get (at least formally)
$$J'(\xi) = \int_\Omega p \, |f - \xi|^{p-2} \, (f - \xi) \, \mathrm d\mu.$$
For $p = 2$, this is $0$ iff $\xi$ is the mean of $f$. But this is not true for $p \ne 2$.

Comment: Thank you. I must have misremembered something and instead of checking if the statement is true or not first, I tried to find a nonexistence proof.